# Let (X, T ) be a topological space. Then T is the discrete topology on X iff Bd(A) = ∅ for every A ⊆ X.

Tags: general-topology

prove or disprove:

Let (X, T ) be a topological space. Then T is the discrete topology on X iff Bd(A) = ∅ for every A ⊆ X.

I think it is false statement, but I do not know how can I come with counterexample  any help please

Comment: try proving it. If the statement is false, a failed attempt at proving it will usually result in a good counterexample.

Comment: You can find one implication here: [Boundary of set A in discrete topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1440100). (The easier one.)

Answer (score 3):

When unable to find a counterexample, one should always try to give proof. The statement is indeed true. If $T$ is not the discrete topology, we can take a subset $A \subseteq X$ which is not closed. Then $\overline{A}$ properly contains $A$ and so $\partial A = \overline{A}\setminus A^\circ$ is non-empty.

Comment: you mean the statement is true?

Comment: so, how can I PROVE it since it has two side (iff)

Comment: I literally said the statement is true. I proved one direction for you. You can try proving the other direction. It is easier.

Comment: ok, thank you so much

Comment: I am waiting you

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: help me with the other side please

Comment: If $T$ is the discrete topology, then for any subset $A \subseteq X$, both $\overline{A}$ and $A^\circ$ are equal to $A$ since $A$ is open and closed (since $T$ is discrete topology). So $\partial A = \overline{A}\setminus A^\circ = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 3):

A useful theorem to prove is
      bd A is empty iff A is clopen.
Next show every subset of a discrete space is clopen.